# Accessing different columns from DataFrame in transform

Tags: python, pandas, transformation

I want to write a transformation function accessing two columns from a DataFrame and pass it to `transform()`.

Here is the DataFrame which I would like to modify:
`print(df)`

```
    date   increment  
0  2012-06-01          0  
1  2003-04-08          1  
2  2009-04-22          3  
3  2018-05-24          6  
4  2006-09-25          2  
5  2012-11-02          4
```

I would like to increment the year in column date by the number of years given variable increment. The proposed code (which does not work) is:

```
df.transform(lambda df: date(df.date.year + df.increment, 1, 1))
```

Is there a way to access individual columns in the function (here a lambda function) passed to `transform()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) :

```
# If necessary convert to date type first
# df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] = df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['increment'], unit='Y')
```

[out]

```
                 date  increment
0 2012-06-01 00:00:00          0
1 2004-04-07 05:49:12          1
2 2012-04-21 17:27:36          3
3 2024-05-23 10:55:12          6
4 2008-09-24 11:38:24          2
5 2016-11-01 23:16:48          4
```

---

or alternatively:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime({'year': df.date.dt.year.add(df.increment),
                             'month': df.date.dt.month,
                             'day': df.date.dt.day})
```

[out]

```
        date  increment
0 2012-06-01          0
1 2004-04-08          1
2 2012-04-22          3
3 2024-05-24          6
4 2008-09-25          2
5 2016-11-02          4
```

---

Your own solution could also be fixed by instead using the `apply` method and passing the `axis=1` argument:

```
from datetime import date

df.apply(lambda df: date(df.date.year + df.increment, 1, 1), axis=1)
```